# Reset/reinstall the gui desktop on 16.04

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, gui

Well, things were going along pretty ok for my first 6+ months with Ubuntu 16.04 which I installed on it's own hard drive, the 3rd internal drive in a system that I kept dual-boot with Windows.

After coming back from vacation, and using system for a day, decided to answer OK to the prompt to install (a month's worth) of Ubuntu updates. Big mistake. The process froze (was updating something Wine related) for hours, forcing me to power off the system.

Since then, I have not been able to successfully boot into the GUI. At this point, I've spent days and tried so many things who knows what else I've messed up - but the basic problem remains: I can boot in recovery mode, to terminal, and every now and then I was successful at getting the graphical login screen to show, but the best I ever got from logging in then was a really messed up desktop with no top bar, so side bar, ability to work with only 1 thing at a time, all the desktop icons on top of one another and blank squares instead of the graphics....

I had nVidia proprietary drivers and I think the original problem related to that - and I tried removing all the nVidia stuff, but some logs seemed to indicate some version problem with something in kernel vs the /.

Since I can boot, and operate in terminal mode, isn't there some way I can just totally re-install the GUI system and video drivers? 
I got to the point where if I could, I'd reinstall Ubuntu, but I don't seem to get any option to reinstall on top of my existing (LVM) installation - only totally wipe everything....

I thought I had a backup of the system, but I guess not really everything I need. I've been backing up from /, but I guess that doesn't include the kernel or something needed to boot up and there's mis-match between the kernel and the system/video or something. Super frustrated.

Answer (score 1):

Safest thing I would try, is downloading Ubuntu 17.10 and letting the system see it as a distro upgrade. Could fix some / all your issues.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion - it worked - sort of.... I can log in and get a desktop as long as I use 'Unity' for the desktop. All the other 3 options for GNOME Compiz, etc. accept my password, the screen goes off, and then comes back to the logon screen... I wonder if I should just leave things as are, or should I try to fix that (uninstall / re-install something? )  But, I can only boot at all if I use recovery mode - it will hang immediately if I try the normal bootup....

Comment: I'm sure this is probably a "Wayland" vs "Xorg" thing. Outside of installing a "fresh" installation of 17.10, I don't know how to fix your black screens.